# How to read in JSON file and write as JSON Lines file in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a JSON file that I'd like to convert to JSON Lines in spark scala. I was able to figure it out in Python by just using Pandas read_json method and then writing it with some special lines parameters passed in.

Say the original format is:

```
{
            "A": "400",
            "B": "100",
            "C": "DEM",
            "D": "USD",
            "E": "80029898",
            "F": "1.64110-",
            "G": "0 "

        },
        {
            "A": "400",
            "B": "100",
            "C": "USD",
            "D": "DEM",
            "E": "80029898",
            "F": "1.64110 ",
            "G": "0 ",

        },
```

I'd like to write is as:

```
{"A":"400","B":"100","C":"DEM","D":"USD","E":"80029898","F":"1.64110-","G":"0"}
{"A":"400","B":"100","C":"USD","D":"DEM","E":"80029898","F":"1.64110 ","G":"0"}
```

Thanks so much and have a great day!

Comment: The input format is a comma separated list of JSONs or should there be brackets `[...]` ?

Comment: comma separated list of JSONs

Comment: JSONs can be read using `spark.read.json()`, and written using `df.write.json()`. Refer [this](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-and-write-json-file/) link for more info and to build on your case

Answer (score 1):

If you are using > spark 2.2, you can use :

```
spark.read
  .option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .json("/path/to/user.json")
```

and then use to write it in desired format:

```
df.write.json()
```